# Extjs update for all grid row not working

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs 3.2grid.I have 5 Records.I am also stoping user to select multiple rows at a time.In grid i have button say approve.What i want is once user selects one record and clicks on approve the selected row coloumn **"showRecord"** will become 1 and remaing rows will become with **showrecord**:0

Here is my code

```
    var proxy_surv = new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    type: 'ajax',
    api : {
        read : 'test/view.action?test='+testid_para+'&flag='+0,
        create : 'test/create.action',
        update : 'test/update.action',
        destroy : 'test/delete.action'
    }
});

var store_surv = new Ext.data.Store({
    id : 'store_surv',
    proxy : proxy_surv,
    reader : reader,
    autoSave : false
// <-- false would delay executing create, update, destroy
// requests until specifically told to do so with some [save]
// buton.
});


store_surv.on({
    beforeload: {
        fn: function (store, options) {
            // Altering the proxy API should be done using the public
            // method setApi.
            store_surv.proxy.setApi('read', 'test/view.action?test='+testid_para+'&flag='+0);

        }
    }
});
```

And here is my logic

```
tbar: [{
iconCls: 'icon-user-add',
text: 'Approve',
handler: function(){


// Server hasn't returned yet for these two lines.
    var survgrid=Ext.getCmp('grid_surv');
    getstore =survgrid.getStore();
    count =getstore.getCount();
    var selected = survgrid.getSelectionModel().getSelected();


    getstore.each(function(record){


             if(parseInt(record.get('id'))==parseInt(selected.get('id')))
             {   

                 record.set('showRecord','1');

              }
              else 
              {

                      record.set('showRecord','0');
              }

            record.commit();

    });

 store_surv.save();


}
}
```

My problem is its not saving in database

Answer (score 0):

don't use `record.commit()` it will say the record that all changes have been changed. it gets automatically called by `store.sync()`. remove `record.commit()` and it should work. you could also use 'record.save()' which will sync a single record.